# Significance of the estimation theorem and its proof

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am reading "Introduction to Complex Analysis" by H.A. Priestley and came across the "Estimation Theorem" (p.125) which states that:
$$\lvert\int_{\gamma} {f(z)dz}\rvert \le \int_{a}^{b}{|f(\gamma (t))\gamma'(t)|dt}$$
where $\gamma$ is a path with parameter interval $[a,b]$ and $f:\gamma[a,b] \to \mathbb{C} $ is a continuous function. This also implies that if $|f(z)| \le M $ for all $z \in \gamma[a,b]$:

$$\int_{\gamma}{|f(z)dz|} \le M \times length(\gamma) $$

What is the proof of these two statements and how are they deduced? And what is their significance (especially from a geometrical standpoint).

Comment: Basically the estimation lemme is awesome because we can show that arc integrals along a certain contour evaluate to zero. As in, they are negligible terms. As for a proof, well, I can type up an answer but I’m not near my laptop at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The first inequality is a trivial consequence of the inequality$$\left\lvert\int_a^b\varphi(t)\,\mathrm dt\right\rvert\leqslant\int_a^b\bigl\lvert\varphi(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt;$$apply it to $(f\circ\gamma).\gamma'$. It follows from this that if $M$ is an upper bound of $\lvert f\rvert$, then\begin{align}\int_a^b\left\lvert f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma'(t)\right\rvert\,\mathrm dt&\leqslant\int_a^bM\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&=M\int_a^b\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&=M\times\operatorname{length}(\gamma).\end{align}

Comment: Ok so since we are integrating on the path $\gamma$ we can parameterise $z = \gamma(t)$, then from here it follows that $dz = \gamma'(t) dt$ therefore the RHS term of the first inequality should $\int_{a}^{b}{|f(\gamma (t))| \gamma'(t) dt}$ right? However, in the book even $\gamma'(t)$ is included within the modulus brackets. Why is that?

Comment: I've also put $\gamma'(t)$ within the absolute value. Otherwise, the inequality doesn't even make sense. What hapens if $\gamma'(t)$ takes complex non-real values?

Comment: Ok so $\gamma' (t)$ has to be positive (since the RHS would be negative???)?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Since $\gamma$ is an arbitrary differentiable path, $\gamma'(t)$ can be any complex number.